# Passing parameter in javascript function is giving error

Tags: javascript, function, extjs

I am using extjs grid , and i put a render function on a coloumn of a grid

```
/** 
    * function for rendering the link
    **/
    function linkRenderer(data, cell, record, rowIndex, columnIndex, store) {
        console.log(record.id);
        if  (data != null)  {
            return '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="resellerwindow('+record.id+')">' + data + '</a>';
        }
        return data;
    }
```

while on clicking the link i got an error that `whatever the value of record.id is not not defined`

Please suggest what solution i can do .

Comment: open firebug or similar and check the properties of record prior to calling linkRenderer. Chances are that you are not passing the thing you think you are.

Comment: What does the console.log output?

Comment: @ChrisR m getting the value in string like city name i am using here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a `idProperty` set for your store? set the idProperty to one of the values used to identify unique records. This will ensure that `record.id` is set to a value. For accessing all other values of the record, you will have to access them through `record.data.proerty`

**Update:** You need to use escape characters so that the string values are properly passed to the resellerwindow method:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="resellerwindow(\''+record.id+'\')"> + data + '</a>'
```

Comment: Yeah  `  idProperty: 'cityname',`

Comment: did you check your generated HTML is correct after rendering the grid? use firebug and check a particular cell's HTML

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="resellerwindow(bangalore)">68</a> it is this

Comment: there you go.. you are missing a quotes it should be: resellerwindow("bangalore").. since you are passing a string to the method

Comment: Abdel nice idea of checking in firebug

Comment: Now please suggest how should i write the line              return '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="resellerwindow('+record.id+')">' + data + '</a>';
and update the answer .

Comment: If you still didn't get it: '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="resellerwindow(\''+record.id+'\')">'

Comment: '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="resellerwindow(" '+record.data.cityname+' ")">'+ data +'</a>'; this is what i tried but giving error

Answer (score 0):

But that's pretty clear the value of record.id is not define. Dah!

Answer (score 0):

If the output of your console log is a string you are calling your function wrong, you are missing some quotes if record.id is a string.

```
function linkRenderer(data, cell, record, rowIndex, columnIndex, store) {
    if  (data != null)  {
        return String.format('<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="resellerwindow(\'{0}\')">{1}</a>', record.id, data);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: String.format is a method on the String object in ExtJS. check the docs: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=String